# Revisiting major FLOSS announcements

Tags: discussion

In the question [Would major FLOSS announcements be on topic?](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/would-major-floss-announcements-be-on-topic), it [was decided](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/a/393/98) that they aren't. However, the top answer also suggests that Meta might be a better venue for such things:

> Another note: while debating this with myself, I've come up with the notion that Meta might be a slightly better place for it. If we had a tag on meta, heavily regulated by mods and top users, and a list of specific projects we'd announce for, that could work.

That post was written when we had no mods. Now that we do, what interest is there in creating such a tag for announcements? Obviously, it requires defining criteria; that could be done in another meta post and copied to the tag wiki.

Do we want this?

Answer (score 9):

The issue with this is that it really isn't a good fit for a Q & A format. Also, we don't even allow "support" questions for our scope so it may be awfully confusing as questions that are "announcements about specific projects" are fine, but questions aren't. That's against the Q & A Model. Also, this could be spam, and very hidden too. And we're not going to advertise freely for random projects.

So... no. Let's not.

Comment: But you can announce anything you like in Chat!

Comment: Yep, @curiousdannii Chat could work. If you peeps wants feeds in, you guys will have to check in with me :)